# How do I install additional molules for Python(x,y)?

Tags: python

I always used Phython(x,y) for college programming because it makes my life a lot easier.
I never needed to worry about the headache of installing new modules because all modules I needed until then came along with Python(x,y).

The problem is that right now I need "mlpy" module, but I can't find a way to integrate it with Python(x,y) and I can't find if really there is a way to do it.

Already tried mlpy ".exe" installer and its "setup.py", but with no success.

Is there an easy way of doing it?

EDIT: I want to use an DTW function. That's why I need `mlpy`. I won't need mlpy if Python(x,y) already has a module with an DTW function. The problem is: I can't find this function.

Comment: What exactly happened that made setup.py fail?

Comment: When I run setup.py, it doesn't show me any error messages, but I still can't run `import mlpy` without getting "ImportError: No module named mlpy".

Comment: You need to run `setup.py install` from the command line, not just `setup.py`.

Comment: this time I ran "setup.py install" and got "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

Comment: try to use pip? In CMD write pip install mipy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time I got it.

Python(x,y) is a Python 2.7 distribution.

I was trying to install `mlpy` module for Python 3.5.

That was the problem.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help :)